# How can I change the background color of the GIT Annotation column for Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Bad background color!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The color for annotations is configured in Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | VCS.

However, this is not a default color and does not look like a configuration issue. Seems like there was a theme switch recently from Darcula to Light, and annotations background is still from Darcula.
Check if reopening project or restarting IDE helps.

Comment: Bingo!  Yes, I was using a theme that I found on the web that copied Eclipse (I know.  I'm an idiot).   In VCS I changed VCS Annotations | Foreground.  Bam, it all showed up.  Thanks!